# Can't reshape the numpy array containing PNG images

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, machine-learning

I've trained a Handwritten image classifier using Keras library in Python. Initially I've used standard MNIST dataset for training and testing purpose. But now I want to use my own data set for testing, in which all the images are size `900*1200*3` instead of `28*28*1`

So I need to reshape all the images before testing. I'm using following code to reshape but it give errors.

**Code:**

```
bb =  lol.reshape(lol.shape[0], 28, 28, 1).astype('float32')
```

where `lol` is my numpy array containing 55 images of shape `(900,1200,3)`

and the Error log is as following:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-46-87da95da73e9> in <module>()
     24 #     # you can show every image
     25 #     img.show()
---> 26 bb =  lol.reshape(lol.shape[0], 28, 28, 1).astype('float32')
     27 # model = loaded_model
     28 # classes = model.predict(bb)

ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 178200000 into shape (55,28,28,1)
```

So what am I doing wrong? Can I get accurate predictions even after resizing the large images to very small images of 28*28?  Thanks for help.

Comment: Shouldn't you change : `lol.reshape(lol.shape[0], 28, 28, 1).astype('float32')` to use the new image shape, which is `900 x 1200x 3`?

Comment: `900 x 1200x 3` is my current shape. I want to reshape in `28,28,1`

Comment: Do you know what `reshape` does?

Comment: You cannot reshape a object of size `55 x 900 x 1200 x 3` in an object of size `55 x 28 x 28 x 3` without losing data. You need to resize your images, not reshape your array.

Comment: Yes, this is RGB -> Grayscale (3 -> 1) + Resize. That's not what reshape does.

Comment: Furthermore, you risk getting really poor results if you try to use resized 900x1200x3 (unless the complexity of your images is poor). You should modify your Keras model to handle bigger images. (more layers)

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing is wrong. You can't reshape an array of (55, 900, 1200, 3) into an array of (55, 28, 28, 1), because you are trying to store 55*900*1200*3=178200000 elements in an array that can store only 55*28*28=43120 elements.

You want to do two things:

**1)** Convert your rgb image (indicated by the last dimension which is the 3 channels) into grayscale (1 channel). The simplest way to do this is (R+B+G)/3. All python libraries that have to do with images (PIL, OpenCV, skimage, tensorflow, keras, etc) have this already implemented. Example:

```
from skimage.color import rgb2gray
gray = rgb2gray(original)
```

**2)** Resize the image from 900x1200 to 28x28. Again you can do this in all major image-related python libraries. Example:

```
from skimage.transform import resize
resized = resize(gray, (28,28))
```

Now if you want to do this in all 55 images you can either write a function that transforms one image and map it across your array, or use a simple for loop and populate your new array one image at a time.

In your case the code should look something like this:

```
num_images = lol.shape[0] # 55 in your case
resized_images = np.zeros(shape=(num_images, 28, 28, 1)) # your final array
for i in range(num_images):
    gray = rgb2gray(lol[i,:,:,:]) # gray.shape should be (900,1200,1)
    resized = resize(gray, (28,28)) # resized.shape should be (28,28,1)
    resized_images[i,:,:,:] = resized # resized_images.shape should be (55,28,28,1)
```

Comment: thanks for replay. But after performing your second step, When I print shape of `resized`, it gives `28*28*1200`, but what I need is `28*28*1`.

Comment: What is the shape of the grayscale array?

Comment: it's 55,1200,900

Comment: The functions need one image at a time to work. I edited my post to include how to do it in your case. I haven't tested it, if it doesn't work tell me and I'll fix it.

Answer (score 1):

It would be more intuitive to process each image individually, which would also give you the best chance of preserving some information.

Try using the PIL library:

```
import numpy
from PIL import Image

lol = numpy.zeros((55,900,1200,3),dtype=numpy.uint8)
new_array = numpy.zeros((lol.shape[0],28,28),dtype=numpy.float32)

for i in range(lol.shape[0]):
    img = Image.fromarray(lol[i])
    img_resize = img.resize((28,28))
    img_mono = img_resize.convert('L')
    arr = numpy.array(img_mono,dtype=numpy.uint8)
    new_array[i] = arr
```